# Troubleshooting independent Vue2 components with different root elements

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

[image: Unknonw custom element]

I'm getting the message above when I do this: https://gist.github.com/komplexb/b7d59ceeb26db7f6e5c2ec7612ef3746

I don't understand why.

N.B. Not an SPA

Comment: Are you getting any other errors? If you are, then this error would be a direct result of the prior errors. You have the tag `vuejs2` in this question, so I would assume that this might be the case. For instance, interpolation errors now exist in 2.x where you can't use `{{}}` syntax inside of HTML element attributes. An example would be `<div id="{{some_id}}">` being bad whereas `<div :id="some_id">` would be valid. You'll need to use `v-bind` or colon syntax. I mention this example specifically because you're using interpolation in an invalid manner for 2.x.

Comment: Additionally, be sure to use the development version if you're not already or you may not be getting all of the errors you would otherwise.

Comment: @B.Fleming Already using dev version. This is the only error it's showing.

Seems unusual for interpolation to be the issue when mustache is instructed for changing portions of text. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Text

Comment: It's strange that you're not getting any other errors. I would still encourage you to update the mustache syntax for HTML attributes. While it's perfectly valid and intended for changing displayed text, it's actually not valid at all for HTML attributes. Having done my fair share of Vue.js development for production features already, I've found that attempting to use it in that way causes failing errors and that you absolutely must use colon or v-bind syntax in those situations.

Comment: @B.Fleming pretty sure none of my syntax was like your example: `An example would be <div id="{{some_id}}"> being bad whereas <div :id="some_id"> would be valid.`

Switching to v-text over mustache hasn't made a difference.

Added entire error message to the original question.